# looking for a regex to find and reorder a string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

i'm looking for a regex to find the CSS shortcut character pattern form top-right-bottom-left (ie: 10px 20px 40px 0) and swap item number 2 with item number 4 (swap left and right). preferably this regex should be able to identify px values as well as % and em, and will take into account that 0 can be present without any identifier.

Comment: This is a bit confusing. Please show some examples (before/after comparisons) that cover all of your requirements.

Comment: before: "10px 20px 4px 5px"
after: "10px 5px 4px 20px"
 - and also - 
before: "1em 2px 50% 12px"
after: "1em 12px 50% 2px"

hope this clears things up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regex like this:

```
(\d+(?:px|em|%)?)\s+(\d+(?:px|em|%)?)\s+(\d+(?:px|em|%)?)\s+(\d+(?:px|em|%)?)
```

And implement it like so:

```
$subject = '10px 20% 40px 0';
$result = preg_replace('/(\d+(?:px|em|%)?)\s+(\d+(?:px|em|%)?)\s+(\d+(?:px|em|%)?)\s+(\d+(?:px|em|%)?)/i', '$1 $4 $3 $2', $subject);
echo $result; // Prints: 10px 0 40px 20%
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = 'margin: 10px 20px 40px 0; padding: 10px 20px 40px 0;';
$pattern = '/((margin|padding|border)\:)(\s*\S+)(\s+\S+)(\s+\S+)(\s+[^;.]+)/i';
$replacement = '$1$3$6$5$4';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string, -1, $count);
```

Comment: You can use a non capturing group for your alternation `(?:margin|padding|border)`, then `$2` is not useless gone.

Comment: sorry, no go. in the css file i can see a valid statement translated into >>padding: 15px "\201C" "\201D" quotes: 10px;;<< and also a border statement translated into >>background: url( 0; padding:../images/bodyBg.jpg) repeat<<  (repeat was damaged)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this:

```
(0|\d+(?:px|em|%))\s(0|\d+(?:px|em|%))\s(0|\d+(?:px|em|%))\s(0|\d+(?:px|em|%))
```

and replace with

```
$1 $4 $3 $2
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2vdeo)

**Explanation:**

This expression consists of 4 capturing groups that are equal, so I explain only one.

This is a capturing group because of hte brackets around the expression. The second pair of brackets has a `?:` after the opening bracket, because of that its a non capturing group. Its just to group the alternatives and I don't need the partial result stored.

```
(0|\d+(?:px|em|%))
```

This expression matches either a 0 or a series of digits (`\d+`) followed by `px`, `em`, or `%`.

Those expressions are put together using a `\s` a whitespace character.